# If A is a nonempty compact set, prove that there exist points x,y in A such that diam(A) = d(x,y)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

So I came across a question in my book that I wanted to prove:

"If A is compact in M, prove that diam(A) is finite. Moreover, if A is nonempty, show that there exist points x and y in A such that $diam(A) = d(x,y)$"

After fixing a few mistakes I came up with the following, for the second part:

A is compact in M, so A is complete. Therefore A is closed in M. That is, A contains all of its limit points. We can make a sequence of points $(x_n) \rightarrow x$ and $(y_n) \rightarrow y$ such that $d(x,y) = diam(A)$ (I won't go into how, but it's quite logical, atleast I thougth so). Because A contains all of its limit points, $x,y \in A$.

When I looked at the answer provided, it used a different approach than I did. As an alternative answer to the different approach, it said:

"Prove that $A \times A$ is compact. Because $d$ is continuous on $A \times A$, it takes its maximum on $A \times A$. Hence $x,y \in A$."

I then noticed that I made a mistake, atleast I think so. I am trying to type why what I did is wrong, but I can't completely wrap my head around it. Can anyone explain my mistake? I have tried to revise my proof but I don't know how to phrase it. My key in understanding why this is supposed to be true is that because A is closed, it contains its supremum. Therefore $diam(A) = sup{d(x,y): x,y \in A}$ must have that $d(x,y)$ is in A. I think the provided answer corrects me by saying that this is only so because $d$ is continuous, which I understand, but then I don't know how to phrase the proof like that.
So in short; what are the mistakes I am making, why are they wrong and how to I revise my proof to get to the correct result?

Thanks!

P.S. I found a similar question on here that quotes the same proof as my provided answer, but that did not help me understand my mistake.

Comment: Why do you think your proof is wrong, and not just a different valid solution?

Comment: I asked the teacher and he responded with: "Note that X is some abstract metric space and not the real numbers. Hence there is no such thing as a 'supremum of a closed set' or an 'interval'." (I rephrased the proof a little to make the sequence precise, because before I said "a sequence of intervals with increasing width that converge to diam(A)". In essence it should still be the same, I think?)

Comment: Which definition of compactness do you use?

Comment: A metric space is said to be compact if it is both complete and totally bounded. Is that enough?

Comment: That's one characterisation of compactness of metric spaces, although there are many. Your revision is incorrect for the reasons your teacher said: "A contains its supremum" makes no sense. Your original proof is also correct (modulo details).

Comment: If the defnition is "complete + totally bounded", do you know the theorem that each sequence has a convergent subsequence?

Comment: Yes I have heard of it, that's the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem right, or atleast a characterisation of it?